# How to get location that isn't out of date?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

After GPS is enabled, it will take some time before the GPS is ready. So use this code may get a location that is out of date:
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
I can't use the location that is out of date. How can I get the location that I need?

Here is a similar question:
[Android: getLastKnownLocation out-of-date - how to force location refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056163/android-getlastknownlocation-out-of-date-how-to-force-location-refresh)

From it, I can use LocationListener to get the updated location, which should be not out of date. It's correct. But how can I handle this case:

I have already enabled GPS, and then start my app. If I stay at one place and don't move, then onLocationChanged() won't be called. So I can't use this method to judge whether the return value of getLastKnownLocation() is not out-of-date?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get location that isn't out of date?

You call `requestLocationUpdates()` with the minTime of 1000 ms, for every `Location` in `onLocationChanged()`, you call `getAccuracy()`. If the accuracy is acceptable for you, call `removeUpdates()`.

> So I can't use this method to judge whether the return value of getLastKnownLocation() is not out-of-date

I think the Location object that it returns will contain a [time stamp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29). You can set a tolerance for the time difference between now and the Location's `getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

Each `Location` object has a `getTime()` method, which returns the time of the fix. You could use that to determine how old the fix is.

Comment: It seems very helpful for the timestamp. Thanks.